# The Painted Barcode

Tags: word, cipher, visual

Someone spilled paint on what looks to be some sort of barcode, although I am not entirely sure that's what it is.

Can you figure out what the original message may have been?

[image: puzzle]

**Hint 1**

> Some rectangles may have gotten a little splattered with paint, but no part of the puzzle has gone missing completely.

**Hint 2**

> The extra space at the bottom of the image was left there intentionally as a hint

**Hint 3**

> The answer is 7 letters long

Comment: This is a lot of hints very quickly - usually people wait at least a day before any hint drop. Keep in mind this is an international community, and people are on at different times of day.

Comment: @bobble I'm just very excited about the puzzle xD. I think the last hint is a pretty big one, so I think I'll slow down for now.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The original message was

> DEFACED (literally!)

The bars correspond to

> dots in [English Braille](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/English_Braille#Alphabet) letters.

Comment: You are correct!

Comment: Great answer!!!

Comment: Clever question. :)